# powershell escaping the escape character in a replace

Tags: string, powershell, replace, escaping

Update - tried text without any back ticks still not replacing.

I have a file test.txt with these records:

```
name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ"` owner="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ"
name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ" owner="RED_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ"
```

I would like to replace the string for the name attribute so I would use

```
name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ"
```

In the powershell script. This is what I did but the output file does not contain the replaced text, it is the same as the input.

Then I use a batch script that has this powershell command in the batch script

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content "test.txt") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ"', 'name="BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ"'} | Set-Content "testo.txt""
```

The batch script does not replace the string that contains the string.
Am I doing something wrong, do I have to escape the double quotes for the string? 
It is still not working for me.

### End update

I am trying to use Powershell to replace some text in a file that makes use of the back tick. 
In the file there is text such as

' name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_`FREQ"'
I would like to replace this text by

```
' name="BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ"'
```

The replace that I use in Powershell look like this

```
powershell -command "& {(Get-Content "file.txt") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace ' name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_`FREQ"', ' name="BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ"'} | Set-Content "fileO.txt;}"
```

The ' name= is needed since there are multiple strings that contain the name="... string.

When I use this command nothing gets replaced. I have tried to escape the back tick by using a double back tick (``) and still nothing gets replaced. 
I have searched and read many articles about Powershell and replacing text and the need for escaping characters. I thought I did what was needed but nothing gets replaced.

How do I replace the text that includes a back tick?

Comment: The problem could be caused by passing the script via the -command parameter. All the quote marks might be messing things up. It would be better to put the script in a file.

Comment: I figured it out. The double quotes and the back tick have to be escaped in the batch script. The replace string to PS ends up being {$_ -replace ' name=\"BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_\`FREQ\"', ' name=\"BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ\"'} Then it works for the back tick or not. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that when a replace is used in a batch script and the text contains either a back tick character or a double quote, then all the back ticks and the double quotes need to be escaped in the batch script. 
The powershell command that was

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content "test.txt") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ"', 'name="BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ"'} | Set-Content "testo.txt""
```

Becomes:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content "test.txt") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'name=\"BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_FREQ\"', 'name=\"BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ\"'} | Set-Content "testo.txt""
```

If there is a back tick in the string then the back tick must be escaped as well using the reverse slash such as

```
\`
```

What a mess in a batch script.
Thanks for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think your command have error that's why it is not changed. You missed the double quote after the txt, before the semicolon.

I tried this in my powershell and it is working.

```
(Get-Content "C:\test.txt") | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace ' name="BLUE_TBL_AC_EA_`FREQ"', ' name="BLUE_TBL_ACEAFREQ"'} | Set-Content "C:\test.txt"
```